# Make "system setting" the default for the Theme setting

Tags: discussion, bug, status-declined, dark-mode

A couple days ago I enabled the dark mode on my Linux machine, and quite a lot of pages I used automatically switched to their respective dark mode version (for example, YouTube).

Stack Overflow was the only site I found that supports a dark mode, but does not automatically enable it when requested by the browser. I checked the settings page and found the theme settings, which were set to "Light" for my account, instead of being set to "System default" as I would expect.

In addition, guests will also always see the light mode without a way to switch to the dark mode (at least I haven't found a way).

Is there a reason the "system default" setting isn't the default, both for logged-in users and guests? Of course logged-in users could still use that setting if they want to have a different theme than their browser's default setting, but in general shouldn't a website honor the setting that's been set in the OS / browser and not force the user to select yet another theme? That's the reason that setting is in the browser, so you don't have to enable it on every webpage...

Or ... is "system default" Stack Overflow's default and I manually set it to "Light" at some point in the past and forgot about that? Unlikely, as when I visit the page as guest I still get the light theme.
Or is this all because the dark mode is still considered Beta, and "system default" will be made the default at some point in the future?

Answer (score 4):

**Update May 2021**
After discussing this internally, we decided to make this request [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

As Scratte points out, some people set dark mode on their OS but prefer light mode on sites. If we default to enabling dark mode based on system defaults, we may confuse a high proportion of users with this sudden change.

We feel the safest thing to do is continue as is: enable light mode by default and allow users to [manually configure dark mode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current) if that's their preference.

---

Thank you for bringing this up! This has been on my mind a bit since GitHub just announced their dark mode beta.

When we launched our dark mode in April of 2020, it was very firmly a beta with a lot of rough edges. We didn’t want to enable a possibly broken experience to everyone by default. Now that our dark mode is out of beta and way more mature, we can now reconsider our default mode, and possibly move that out from behind a user setting.

After all, it makes sense that if your system prefers dark mode, we would show dark mode.

Looking into it!

Comment: Some users, like me, have dark mode on their OS, but prefer light mode on sites. If you can enable public to switch that would probably make most users happy.

Comment: It should still be a user-configurable setting, @Scratte. The question is whether the dark theme is mature enough now to make it the *default* when the user has dark mode set in their OS.

Comment: I'm not referring to a Stack Overflow user. I'm referring to a guest. If the default is set to everyone's OS setting, most people using Stack Overflow will may not have a choice, unless it's possible for "public to switch". [This is the option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtLbL.png) unregistered users with no account, like me, gets at youtube to get back to light mode.

Comment: @aaron-shekey any updates on this one?

Comment: @anita-taylor Since this update is somewhat different from the original answer, I think you should probably post it as a separate answer so people can vote/comment on it separately.

Comment: If someone configures their OS to be dark, and expects the sites to be light mode, they can specifically configure it, because they don't want the default setting. But most people would want dark mode on their OS and dark mode on their site. In the same way, most people prefer light mode on their os and light mode on their site. I think this feature request would make most people happy, considering that it is a popular one.

Comment: @10Rep Only if they have an account. Most users do not. I can f.ex not change the light/dark mode on GitHub, Pastebin nor twitter. There's no options for that without having an account and logging in. Instead I have to create special user styles to overwrite their forced OS/Browser settings mode. I tried to explain this in my previous comment.

Comment: @Scratte System setting should then also be the default for guests. Thats all the more reason. If the unregistered user sets their system to dark mode, and they get dark mode on SO, then they can change it on their system. Or, like you said, just let the public change their OS. I think we are actually agreeing on the same thing and just not realising it.

Comment: @10Rep I'm only talking about guests, which I made clear on my second comment. I have reasons to have dark mode on my browser, while not using dark mode on sites. Same with my system. The colours of the headers of the windows are just not pleasing with light mode on my system. And they're not editable for f.ex. Opera. Opera in [dark mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q6hm.png), here in [light mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGCXp.png). So I keep my browser in dark mode, so I can see the top bar. For my OS, which I assume is adjustable.. it's just such a hazzle to change all those settings.

Comment: @Scratte your case seems like a rare one. To be clear, you want light mode on all your sites, but dark mode in your browser. Which is all the reason why guests should be allowed to configure, and that's what I said in my comment. Guests should also be able to configure their settings, and "system default" should be the default setting.

Comment: @10Rep You mentioned "Or, like you said, just let the public change their OS", which is *not* what I said, *nor* what I meant. I meant a button on the site itself to toggle between the modes, which is what I tried to show with the screen capture for YouTube. I would perfer users do *not* have to change their OS mode every time they want to visit Stack Overflow or any other site. I'm getting the feeling that I'm just repeating what I already said :(

Comment: @Scratte That should be written as a different feature-request, then. This is just asking for the default to be the system default, which is what _most_ people would prefer. You are asking for customizability for guest users on the site itself. That's not what this feature-request asks.

Comment: @10Rep I do not need to write a feature requests. Stack Overflow is light for me. But before we can discuss what most users would prefer, wouldn't it be best to find out first? How do we know I'm the corner case? At this point, it's just a guess, no?

Comment: @Scratte _I do not need to write a feature requests_ ---> If you want the dropdown, like on YouTube, then write a feature request. Not that hard. As for finding out what most people prefer, that's a dead end for employees, because if they ask on meta, people will say that most of the users who use the site without an account were not asked. And if employees do a survey without asking on meta, the meta user-base will complain.

Comment: @10Rep "Not that hard"? Please don't get snappy with me. That's uncalled for. I don't need nor do I want the dropdown on Stack Overflow. It's working fine for me as it is now. On a side note: I don't think any of the feature-requests i already wrote is getting any attention from Stack. So that's pretty much a waste of time. (With the exception of double-avatars :-)

Comment: @Scratte _I meant a button on the site itself to toggle between the modes, which is what I tried to show with the screen capture for YouTube. I would perfer users do not have to change their OS mode every time they want to visit Stack Overflow or any other site._ ---> That clearly indicates that you wanted that, or that it would be a useful feature, which is why I suggested it. At this point I'm confused, because if it is working for you why would you request it in the first place? It's also a guess on your side, that it would make most users happy, no?

Comment: I don't need to guess that giving uses options to choose make them happier than not having the option. I'd assume that was obvious.

Comment: Yeah, but that should be a seperate feature-request is what I've been saying. And some feature-requests don't get addressed immediately because of the bajilion other things employees have to do.